# Setting standalone = 'YES' using XMLEventWriter

Tags: xml, java-7, java

I'm using 'XMLEventWriter' to generate an XML file in Java. Code snippet is as below:

```
XMLEventWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileWriter(outFile)); 
XMLEvent startEvent = eventFactory.createStartDocument("UTF-8","1.0",true);
writer.add(startEvent);
```

In spite of setting the third argument to 'true', I'm seeing that the generated XML document's header does not have standalone="YES"

Could anyone suggest the changes (if any) to be made to make standalone="yes" appear in the generated XML file's document header ?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the same issue (cf. [java StAX - standalone property of StartDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629709/java-stax-standalone-property-of-startdocument)) and I found that is is unimplemented in my Java version:

package: `com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers`

class `XMLEventWriterImpl`

```java
public void add(javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent xMLEvent) {
  //...
  case XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT :{
    //...
    StreamWriter.writeStartDocument(startDocument.getCharacterEncodingScheme(), startDocument.getVersion());
```

(note that standalone property is not used here)

Then in next call (class `XMLStreamWriterImpl`)

```java
public void writeStartDocument(String encoding, String version)
    throws XMLStreamException {
    //Revisit : What about standalone ?
    //...
```

This is the original comment in the code, so it is unsupported yet unless implemented in Java.

My current java version is:

`java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)`

Maybe it has been fixed in a later version ?

**EDIT**

Just tested with

`java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)`

and the issue still exists.